# Find definition of Classes in Bootstrap

Tags: class

I'm learning bootstrap, and am trying to find the function of the various classes in bootstrap, no least seems to cover even half of all the classes, so is there a way to find the function of the classes within the source code or something?

Comment: What "bootstrap" is it that you're asking about?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4

Comment: Before that, though, is it the CSS framework you're asking about, or something else entirely? Your question doesn't exactly make it clear, and it's not tagged as the CSS framework.